# Live Sample Spotify WEB App

Tags: javascript, api, web-applications, spotify

I am struggling with getting started with the Spotify (WEB) API. The current documentation seems to be missing alot and doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

I've tried several 'kitchen sinks' and starter apps but upon uploading them to my server nothing displays and I don't understand some external files such as 'views' and they don't seem to pull in either.

**Is anyone familiar with a live spotify app demo? Or kind of like a plugin and play set of files and folders where I can start with a base seeing something and kind of poke around and play from there?**

Cheers for any pointers.

**EDIT:**

I am seeking to create a WEB App; in case there was confusion; all recommendations keep mentioning for this to live not on my server (uploaded to the Web).

In general I am seeking to create a web app somewhat similar to:
http://gigfi.com/

Which appears to be powered by a 'results.php' file within the source; of course I cannot see it -- but this what leads to me to believe PHP could be involved.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at Gigfi, it seems that all you need is the [Spotify Play Button](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/), possibly in combination with the [Metadata API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/) (a.k.a. Web API).

The way I see this working, is that you have a database where you've got artists mapped to gigs, and you want a Spotify Play Button for an artist on tour. You need the Spotify URIs (track, artist, playlist, etc. E.g. spotify:artist:1u7kkVrr14iBvrpYnZILJR for Sex Pistols) to create the Spotify Play Button (the playlist in the left column). In order to get those, you can use the Metadata/Web API to make searches so that you can map the artist in your database to its Spotify URI. For example, if you've got Björk, you'd make a request to http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist.json?q=artist:Bj%C3%B6rk, and grab the artists array from the response. The artists are listed in order of popularity, so it's likely that the first artist is what you're looking for, but search isn't perfect. Once you've got the URI, you'd use that as input in the Spotify Play Button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the awesome reply @michaelt! But when you say 'you have a database where you've got artists mapped to gigs' -- am I not able to use Spotifys DB?

Comment: Is there any live fiddles with the Play Button and / or Metadata API implemented and working? (Outside of within native Spotify of course)

Comment: Spotify's APIs doesn't expose any data about upcoming gigs, so you'd have to use some other API to get that - check out [Songkick](https://www.songkick.com/developer).

Comment: The [Developer site](http://developer.spotify.com) host some examples of the Web API and the Spotify Play Button. However, the documentation doesn't cover the actual use of the Web API but rather just the URL scheme that you could use in order to retrieve information about artists, tracks, albums, and so on. What tools you use when using the API is really up to you. There are lots of posts and tutorials on how to use RESTful Web APIs. If you're running Node, you can use [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle) for example.

Comment: @MichaelThelin, now the problem that I am having is that I was able to query the api of a playlist, now when I tried to add uri to the spotify player it only preview the song, and wants me to login ... I don't want that

Answer (score 1):

I understand your pain. Their docs are not in the greatest shape right now.

Here's some things to think about.

a) Spotify's architecture is a fork of Chromium so it's just like any other webpage.

b) From point a, just use your HTML, CSS, and javascript expertise to create the app you want

Why would you want to upload apps to your server? Spotify provides an environment to test your app within the application itself. Do you need a link to that?

Have you built Chrome extensions before? I find the process to be similar in some ways.

EDIT: Addressing your question better

There's no reason Spotify apps can't work in browser. Have you tried putting this boilerplate on your server?

https://github.com/spotify/boilerplate-app

Comment: Hey Tom! Thanks for the answer man; yeah how could test within their app? Cheers

Comment: Check out this section of the docs, if it's still not clear reach me @TMurphyMusic of the Twitters and I'll get an email chain going with you: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/#creatinganapp

Comment: Just to be SUPER clear — apps don't go on your server, they live on your local machine as the link above described.

Comment: Just want to add that Chromium is actually embedded into Spotify using Chromium Embedded Framework (https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/).

Comment: @iKenndac - Web Apps; don't upload to my server to be live on Web? This isn't a desktop application nor native phone app. A Website App.

Comment: @1977 aha! I think that most of us thought you were talking about a desktop app because you mentioned that you had tried 'kitchen sinks'. All of those I've seen for Spotify are for in-application apps.

Answer (score 1):

My app that I've been playing with is open source, if you wanted to test it out (though I've been told that it doesn't work properly on linux).

https://github.com/matelich/album-radio

Also, you tagged this with php.  I don't *think* you can use php in a Spotify app, but I might be wrong.  Just html5/javascript/css.

Comment: Also, giacecco has been doing some public spotify app work - https://github.com/search?q=%40giacecco+spotify

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the suggestion! I'm going to try your app; realistically I could upload it to my server and see it, right; like the index and build on it / tweak it? I'm fairly new to server side development. And my last attempt left me lost because I couldn't see any of the code resolve. Cheers!

Comment: I wonder if you're actually wanting to do something else besides an integrated Spotify app. Spotify apps run inside of the Spotify player adding to its functionality. The links provided in the other answer and its comments give information on this

Answer (score 0):

I think this one works: https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial. I've used it myself.

Some clarifications: a Spotify app is a pure web app, so it uses only HTML, CSS and Javascript. It will depend heavily on the Spotify API library, so it will not run in a browser outside the Spotify client, and it will not run on a server. This is what "Spotify app" means.

What you are (or were) trying to create is possibly something else, maybe a web app utilizing the Spotify API? In that case, try the [web API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/). Examples:

- [http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=kaizers+orchestra](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=kaizers%20orchestra)
- [http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=kaizers+orchestra](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=kaizers%20orchestra)